# Evaluate the following integral with residue

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The integral is $$\int \frac{e^{izt}}{(z+1)^2} dz$$ Where t is a real number which can be positive or negative. I have to calculate the integral for t<0 and t>0. The example says: If necessary, check the $t \rightarrow 0$ boundary condition.
z=-1 is a second order pole.
$$Res(z=-1) = it\cdot e^{-it} $$
In previous examples, for t<0 I integrated over a half-circle below the real axis of the complex plane, and for t>0, I integrated over a half-circle above the real axis. But in this example, I have only 1 pole, and neither of the half circles contains it.

What should I do?

Comment: How about a circle containing the pole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closed contour not containing $-1$, the integral is zero.

Otherwise, if the pole is inside the contour, you get $2\pi i (ite^{-it})=-2\pi te^{-it}$.